# C - function returning pointer to function

Tags: c, function, pointers, memory, memory-management

What is the proper C syntax for a function returning pointer to another function (which again may return a pointer to some thrid function etc)? I know that we can define a function as a local variable inside another function (but we need to know the address or it is useless):

```
int*(*a)(int) = (void*)0;
```

This is local variable `a` which represents a function which has `int` as a parameter and returns pointer to `int`, while the address of the function is `0`. How can I have a function which returns, instead of pointer to `int`, a pointer to a function requiring `char` as a parameter and returning a pointer to `int`?  This is what I've tried:

```
int*(*)(char)(*a)(int) = (void*)0;
```

But, it is a syntax error. Is there a way to do it, or maybe, the only way is to return `void*` and then to cast it again to function?

## Edit

I am not looking only for a solution which works. I know it can be done using `typedef` or just by returning a generic pointer and then casting to another function. But, I am writting a code highlighter for C and I want to cover all cases which are defined by ISO C, so I am wondering does ISO C allow double returning functions, if yes, what is the proper syntax, if no, can it be found somewhere in documentation?

Answer (score 3):

You could use typedefs to simplify this (and make sure you can actually understand the code a week later):

```
typedef int*(*FuncA)(int);
typedef FuncA(*FuncB)();

FuncB a = (void*)0;
```

Obviously use more descriptive names than I have done here.

Comment: In that case, I would try `(int*(*)(char))(*a)(int)` (though I really doubt it would work)

Comment: Edit your question to clarify that you are not interested in the `typedef` solution, or you'll get more of the same if I delete my answer. Futhermore SO is a resource for all developers not just you. My answer is a legitimate answer to your question (just not the one you want) and as such it should remain and be available for other users' benefit (I really don't care about the upvotes)

Comment: I restored your answer because the person who convinced you to delete it is a well-known troll, who only convinced you to delete it so that they could delete the question. If you'd rather this answer be deleted, let me know. Otherwise, you earned the reputation and leaving it intact is good for the community.